# Optical-flow visualizations explained

Tags: computer-vision, visualization, optical-flow

What do the arrows depict in the optical-flow visualizations such as the one below?

[image]

(image source: [learnopencv](https://learnopencv.com/optical-flow-in-opencv/))

Is it correct to say that the pixel at the tip of an arrow was at the origin of the arrow in previous frame?

Comment: It depends! What you say is correct for live / real-time video. But if you're post-processing pre-recorded video then you have all the frames including those at $t+1$.

Comment: @PeterK. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as your linked page shows:

[image: Image from linked page showing displacement]

the idea is that the pixels move from $(x,y)$ in the first from to $(x+\Delta x, y + \Delta y)$ in the second. I believe the image you quote is just connecting a series of $(x_i,y_i)$ with their next locations $(x_i+\Delta x_i, y_i + \Delta y_i).$